# How to work with a teammate using bitbucket and xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, bitbucket

me and my colleague are new to `Bitbucket` and we are working on a project on different together.But the problem is that sometimes when I pull the project, some of the changes made by him is not there, Like created Files or codes.

This is an image of our project repo:

[image: image of our project repo]

We don't exactly understand those colored `branches` and `Merges`,It's confusing since **WE** didn't create any branches.

What is it we are missing?

Comment: Use Rebase instead of simply pull?

Comment: When you run `git pull`, the remote branch is fetched and then merged with your local branch. Although the remote branch and the local branch have the same name, they are technically not the same branch. So the graph shows merged branches. You and your teammate can make a rule, to use `git pull --rebase` only, or `git fetch` + `git rebase`.

Comment: could you please explain what does `rebase` and `fetch` does?

Comment: `git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git merge` by default. `git pull --rebase` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git rebase`. You could google the difference between `git merge` and `git rebase`. `fetch` downloads the commits from the remote repository, those that don't exist in your local repository yet.